# Is the electromagnetic coupling constant of the muon exactly the same value with the electron $α \approx1/137$?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, physical-constants, magnetic-moment, leptons

I am asking because I want to know If I can use the Schwinger equation:

$$a_{e}=\frac{\alpha}{2 \pi} \approx 0.0011614$$

to calculate the one-loop QED contribution to the anomalous magnetic moment of the muon in the same way it is used for the electron?

If yes that would mean that both muon and electron have the same one-loop QED contribution. However, I believe this is not the case here which would infer that electromagnetic coupling of the muon is slightly different from that of the electron, fine structure constant $α \approx1/137$.

**So what is the exact electromagnetic coupling constant of the muon used in the calculations of its anomalous magnetic moment which is by percentage larger than that of the electron?**

Have they considered the possibility of the EM coupling constant to vary for the muon and therefore actually being the main reason for the observed latest Fermilab theoretical-experimental anomalous magnetic muon moment discrepancy with 4.2σ and not any exotic unknown matter?

Ultimately, my question herein is asking if it is possible the fine structure constant (FSC) $α$ to slightly vary among the charged leptons (i.e. electron, muon and tau)?

A first rough calculation using the Schwinger equation and the latest 4.2σ experimental results of muon anomalous magnetic moment would suggest a $FSC_{μ} \approx$ 0.007**325** compared to $\approx$0.007**297** for the electron.

Comment: Why would $\alpha=e^2/(4\pi\varepsilon_0c\hbar)$ only work for one lepton species?

Comment: @J.G. Yes I know, at first glance according to the equation of FSC α, there should be no difference for any of the charged leptons. Nevertheless, keep in mind that this equation calculates the FSC α and not the final EM coupling constant of the particle. It may that there is an additional term for the muon.

Comment: The fine structure constant against general believe is not only correlated with strength of the EM force interaction but has a much deeper correlation with the intrinsic properties of the electron particle and it sources from the electron. Therefore it does not necessarily mean that it will have the exact same value for the muon or tau particles IMO considering also the large mass difference among these particles there might be an additional term.